# non-italic capital greek letters

Tags: greek, italic, capitalization, sv-classes

I am using `svjour3` class to draft my manuscript and have many `\usepackage` in it. The capital greek letters are rendered italic in the output. svjour3 could be obtained from [journal website](http://static.springer.com/sgw/documents/468198/application/zip/LaTeX_DL_468198_220518.zip)

Following is a example (the symbols are italic even when no extra packages are loaded)

```
\documentclass{svjour3}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
This is just the beginning. \\
This is $\Sigma, \Theta$ in italics and I don't want them to be.

\end{document}
```

[image]

How to avoid this? Please do not suggest `\usepackage{upgreek}`.

PS: This manuscript I am writing constitutes of abstracts from my thesis, these symbols render correctly in my thesis Latex draft. There would be many other manuscripts and reports simultaneously going on and I want consistency in all. I believe the problem is created by the class file.

Comment: Please provide us with more information. Why do you not want use that package? Can you provide a Minimal Working Example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that))?

Comment: Please tell us which math font(s) you employ. (I assume you're not using Computer Modern -- CM's uppercase Greek letters are upright, not slanted.)

Comment: @Flexo013: updated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `svjour3` class has

```
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Gamma}{\mathalpha}{letters}{"00}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Delta}{\mathalpha}{letters}{"01}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Theta}{\mathalpha}{letters}{"02}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Lambda}{\mathalpha}{letters}{"03}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Xi}{\mathalpha}{letters}{"04}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Pi}{\mathalpha}{letters}{"05}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Sigma}{\mathalpha}{letters}{"06}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Upsilon}{\mathalpha}{letters}{"07}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Phi}{\mathalpha}{letters}{"08}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Psi}{\mathalpha}{letters}{"09}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Omega}{\mathalpha}{letters}{"0A}
```

because the editorial policy of Springer wants uppercase Greek letters in italics by default.

Use `\mathrm{\Gamma}` and so on if you want them upright. However, you shouldn't be using `svjour3` for other purposes than submissions to Springer journals.

Answer (score 1):

As usual, egreg has a great answer, but I’ll supplement it with a bit of information on how you can select between upright and italic Greek letters.

With a modern toolchain that supports `unicode-math`, you can select `math-style=upright` to get all upright letters, and `math-style=ISO` to get all slanted math letters.  Upright numbers and Greek capital letters with all other letters in math mode italicized is the default, but you can select it explicitly with the option `math-style=TeX`. There is also a fourth `math-style=French` option.  Whatever you select, symbols such as summation and product series remain upright.

Regardless of which option you choose, you can use the commands `\upalpha`, `\upAlpha`, and so on, to get upright Greek letters.  (There is also the syntax `\symup{pi}.)

Capital Greek letters are upright and other letters are italicized by default in legacy NFSS mode as well.  Several packages have the option to change that, including `newpx`, `newtx`, `isomath` and `mathastext`.  Additionally, there are several packages that enable upright Greek letters using commands such as `\uppi`, including `upgreek`.

Unfortunately, commands such as `\mathrm{\pi}` are not supported by all packages. On `unicode-math`, this selects the text font (or is bugged), and some font packages (such as `mathpazo`) make it produce garbage.  Loading a package that supports `\uppi` is safer.  There are additionally a number of fonts to load Greek letters in text mode, although if you want to write Greek words and not just math symbols with legacy packages, you are probably loading `babel` and a LGR-encoded font.